# How to add second level to a submenu in a dropdown navigation css in Blogger

Tags: css, navigation, blogger

I am really struggling with my template. Here is my current css for the navigation menu. I have tried several things but nothing gives me a second submenu that will pop out to the right of the dropdown im already on. Can anyone help me insert code to allow for a second pop out? Thanks!!!

```css
/* CSS Main Menu */

#menu-wrapper {
  background: #353535;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

#menu {
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu ul {
  height: 50px
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu li a {
  color: #fff;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
  color: #f8a82a;
}

#menu li a:hover {
  color: #f8a82a;
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#menu label {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 35px;
  height: 51px;
  line-height: 51px;
  text-align: center
}

#menu label span {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px
}

#menu ul.menus {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 166px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  color: #aaa;
  top: 50px;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover > ul.menus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
  -o-transform: scale(1.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  transform: scale(1.0);
}

#menu a.ai,
#menu a.trigger2 {
  padding: 0 27px 0 14px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

#menu > li:hover > a.ai,
#menu a.ai:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #f8a82a;
}

#menu li > a.ai::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
}

#menu ul.menus a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#menu ul.menus a:hover {
  background: #f8a82a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}

#menu ul.menus li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul.menus li a:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "\f061";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: 0;
  left: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul.menus li a:hover:before {
  left: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu ul.menus li:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

#menu ul.menus li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu ul.menus li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}

#menu ul.menus li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu ul.menus > li:hover > a {
  background: #f8a82a;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 25px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

#menu .ranpost {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

#menu .ranpost:hover {
  background-color: transparent!important;
}

#menu ul.menusub a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#menu ul.menusub a:hover {
  background: #f8a82a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}

#menu ul.menusub li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul.menusub li a:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "\f061";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: 0;
  left: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul.menusub li a:hover:before {
  left: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu ul.menusub li:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

#menu ul.menusub li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu ul.menusub li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}

#menu ul.menusub li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu ul.menusub > li:hover > a {
  background: #f8a82a;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 25px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

#menu .ranpost {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

#menu .ranpost:hover {
  background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu-wrapper'>
  <div class='content-wrapper'>
    <nav id='menu'>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label/>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Static Page</a></li>
        <li><a class='ai' href='#'>Dropmenu</a>
          <ul class='menus'>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class='ai' href='#'>Dropmenu</a>
          <ul class='menus'>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class='ai' href='#'>Dropmenu</a>
          <ul class='menus'>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Button</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Error</a></li>
        <li class='ranpost'>
          <a onclick='feelingLucky();'><i/>Surprise Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='clear' />
```

Comment: Umm, why do you have `&quot` & `&gt;` in your code? If you posted your CSS code with plain text, I could possibly help you.

Comment: That is in the actual code in blogger believe it or not.

If you have access to blogger I could invite you to my blog if that helps. I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Could you open the developer tools and copy the css file from there?

Comment: Ill give that a try. I'm not great at this stuff as you can see. :s

Comment: Didn't copy right at all. http://testblogdtc57.blogspot.com/ May be a bigger problem than its worth.

Comment: Copied from original XML file and it had the &quot and &gt; too. Above codes are newly pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if you edit the HTML & the CSS, here is how you could do it:

## HTML

One of the HTML Dropdown menus look like this:

```
<li><a class='ai' href='#'>Dropmenu</a>
  <ul class='menus'>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Add this code after the Dropmenu `</a>` tag:

```
  <ul class='menus'>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
  </ul>
```

So it to look like this:

```
<li><a class='ai' href='#'>Dropmenu</a>
  <ul class='menus'>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a>
      <ul class='menus'>
        <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

## CSS

Then, add this CSS:

```
#menu .menus li > ul.menus {
  transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.0);
  top: 0;
}

#menu ul.menus {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

## Final Result

It should look like this when you're done:

```css
/* CSS Main Menu */

#menu .menus li > ul.menus {
   transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.0);
   top: 0;
}

#menu ul.menus {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

#menu-wrapper {
  background: #353535;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}

#menu {
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}

#menu ul,
#menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu ul {
  height: 50px
}

#menu li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#menu li a {
  color: #fff;
}

#menu a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
  color: #f8a82a;
}

#menu li a:hover {
  color: #f8a82a;
}

#menu input {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#menu label {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 35px;
  height: 51px;
  line-height: 51px;
  text-align: center
}

#menu label span {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35px
}

#menu ul.menus {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 166px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  color: #aaa;
  top: 50px;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover > ul.menus {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
  -o-transform: scale(1.0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
#menu .menus li > ul.menus {
  transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.0);
  top: 0;
}



#menu a.ai,
#menu a.trigger2 {
  padding: 0 27px 0 14px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

#menu > li:hover > a.ai,
#menu a.ai:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #f8a82a;
}

#menu li > a.ai::after {
  content: "\f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
}

#menu ul.menus a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#menu ul.menus a:hover {
  background: #f8a82a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}

#menu ul.menus li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul.menus li a:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "\f061";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: 0;
  left: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul.menus li a:hover:before {
  left: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu ul.menus li:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

#menu ul.menus li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu ul.menus li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}

#menu ul.menus li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu ul.menus > li:hover > a {
  background: #f8a82a;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 25px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

#menu .ranpost {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

#menu .ranpost:hover {
  background-color: transparent!important;
}

#menu ul.menusub a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#menu ul.menusub a:hover {
  background: #f8a82a;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}

#menu ul.menusub li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul.menusub li a:before {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  content: "\f061";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: 0;
  left: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul.menusub li a:hover:before {
  left: 10px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu ul.menusub li:hover {
  width: 100%;
}

#menu ul.menusub li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu ul.menusub li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}

#menu ul.menusub li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu ul.menusub > li:hover > a {
  background: #f8a82a;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 25px;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

#menu .ranpost {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

#menu .ranpost:hover {
  background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu-wrapper'>
  <div class='content-wrapper'>
    <nav id='menu'>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label/>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Static Page</a></li>
        <li><a class='ai' href='#'>Dropmenu</a>
          <ul class='menus'>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a>
              <ul class='menus'>
                <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class='ai' href='#'>Dropmenu</a>

        </li>
        <li><a class='ai' href='#'>Dropmenu</a>
          <ul class='menus'>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 4</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Dropmenu 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Button</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Error</a></li>
        <li class='ranpost'>
          <a onclick='feelingLucky();'><i/>Surprise Me</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='clear' />
```

Note: instead of:

```
#menu ul.menus {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

You could just remove `overflow: hidden` on `#menu ul.menus`.

## MOBLIE

For mobile support, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621030#43623853).

Comment: For mobile, please add a new question :) I think I got it, but it doesn't belong here.