# Sub-Submenu not appearing on mobile device

Tags: css, mobile, blogger

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024045/), I was able to I was able to add sub-submenu support to my site. However, on mobile, the menus just appear as blank lines.

[image: sub submenu error]

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
#menu .menus li > ul.menus {
  transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.0);
  top: 0;
}
```

with

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 981px) {
  #menu .menus li > ul.menus {
    transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.0);
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

If worst comes to worst, you could **not** replace anything and just add this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  #menu .menus li > ul.menus {
    transform: translateX(100%) scale(1.0) !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome! One last thing, could you go through your comments on both posts and delete the ones that you don't think future readers will find useful? Such as thank you's or questions? Thanks and God bless.